# Connect to Oracle database 11g with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web and Oracle database 11g in Window 8.

When I use GridView to connect the database, I get following error.

> Oracle Client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.
>
> Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/using_aspnt.htm

Answer (score 0):

by installing the oracle drivers http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found this answer from [here](http://oracleerrormsging.blogspot.de/2010/02/could-not-resolve-service-name.html), hope it solves your issue:

> To find out the reason and solutions for this error follow the
>   following steps
>
> 1. Try a test connection in oracle's sql plus utility. If the connection fails you have a bad installation or configuration of
>      oracle client components.
> 2. If the oracle is first installed on IIS you should reboot at once.
> 3. If theire is multiple copies of OCIW32.dll you have to make sure that there is only one copy of OCIW32.dll which should be in /Bin
>      folder of the oracle home folder.
> 4. Add the IUSR_machine name account and the IWAM_machine name account to the Oracle home folder. Give both accounts full control.
>
> To do this, right-click on the Oracle home folder in Windows Explorer.
>   Click Properties, and then click the Security tab. Add the appropriate
>   accounts and then give them full control. Restart your computer.